# Find interval in which function is continuous.

Tags: continuity

Given $f(x) = \frac{x²-2}{4x²+mx+4}$ determine the interval of m which makes f continuous for all real numbers.

I think the answer is $m \in (-8, 8)$ but I dont know how to get to it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
You're searching for $m$ such that $4x^2+mx+4\neq0$, i.e. when the determinant of that polynomial  $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ is strictly negative.

Comment: So m² < 64 and therefore m < 8  and m>-8

Comment: @faruk Correct.

Answer (score 1):

In order for $f(x)$ to be continuous for all real numbers, you need to look at the interval of $m$ at which $4x^2 + mx + 4$ $\neq$ $0$. The quadratic equation has real roots if and only if its discriminant is positive or zero, i.e $\Delta$ $\geqslant 0$. Therefore, you need to find the values of $m$ for which the discriminant is greater than zero, in order to know the interval for which the roots are not real.
$$b^2 -4ac > 0$$
The values which satisfy this inequality are $m < 8$. Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous for all real numbers only when $m<8$.

Comment: $m\lt8$ isn't sufficient, for instance see what happens when $m=-8$ or $m=-16$.